# Definition of weights in meta analysis using random effects generalized linear mixed models?

Tags: r, random-effects-model, meta-analysis, glmm

my understanding of statistics is pretty basic and i have reached my limit with the following.
I am trying to find how the weights of single estimates are defined when using GLMM to calculate pooled estimates.

I know that that random effects weights are assigned in general as the "inverse of the between-study variance plus within-study variance" (w=1/(variance + tau squared).

Is this Definition also correct for the weights assigned when using GLMM?

A very thankful and confused student